# jQuery menu does not show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little problem with this jquery code:
If I call the openMenu function, directly, it works, but inside the if it does not.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 function checkMenu() {

 if($(this).find('ul').css('display') == 'none') {
    openMenu();
 } else { 
    closeMenu();
 }
 }

 function openMenu() {  
    $(this).find('ul').css({display: "block"});
 }

function closeMenu() {
  $(this).find('ul').css({display: "none"});
 }


 $('ul li:has(ul)').click(checkMenu);
 });
```

Comment: use firefox or chrome console to see the errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make it easy on yourself and use `toggle()`

```
$('ul li:has(ul)').click(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I am quite noob with javascript/jquery so I didnt know that function.

Comment: I'd read through their whole API, especially on new releases. They're always adding functionality/changing things

Answer (score 2):

why don't you use .toggle() ? such as:

```
$(this).find('ul').toggle();
```

Also you can set the toggle speed either using slow, normal, fast:

```
$(this).find('ul').toggle('fast');
```

Answer (score 1):

openMenu doesn't know what "this" is referring to. This should work...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function checkMenu() {
    var me = $(this);
    if(me.find('ul').css('display') == 'none') {
        openMenu(me);
    } else {
        closeMenu(me);
    }
}

function openMenu(me) {

    //this isn't defined..
    me.find('ul').css({
        display: "block"
    });
}

function closeMenu(me) {
    me.find('ul').css({
        display: "none"
    });
}


$('ul li:has(ul)').click(checkMenu);
```

});

But the others are right. The toggle function would work really well for something like this.